# Laravel collection structure change

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two APIs for users.

1. returns a single record.
2. returns collection of users.

1st API output structure should be

```json
{
    "message": "Employee record",
    "data": {
        "first_name": "..and so on",
    }
}
```

2nd API output structure should be

```json
{
    "message": "Employee record",
    "data": [
        {
            "first_name": "..and so on",
        },
        {
            "first_name": "..and so on",
        },
    ]
}
```

Can I do this with only UserResource? Or should I create another resource for the collection?

Comment: You don't need to create a `Resource` to represent a collection, just call the `::collection` method on your `UserResource` and it should handle everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

Does it not already do that if you use the doc logic?

```
//routes.php

use App\Http\Resources\UserResource;
use App\Models\User;
//getting the collection of the query
Route::get('/users', function () {
    return UserResource::collection(User::all());
});
see here passing a single record
Route::get('/user/{id}', function ($id) {
    return new UserResource(User::findOrFail($id));
});



//UserResource
namespace App\Http\Resources;
 
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
 
class UserResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'first_name' => $this->first_name
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: It works only if I want to return the data key. But I have a few extra keys along with data.

Comment: What about using $user->only(['first_name']); and if you have multiple just use map function with return $user->only({'first_name']); ?